# 500 Internal error

Tags: flask, nginx, config, ubuntu

Есть удаленный сервер на ubuntu, на нем стоит nginx, это его config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 54.68.200.171
    access_log /var/log/nginx/InstAnalyze/access.log;

     location /static {
         root /home/thmw/InstAnalyze/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
    }
}
```

А также само приложение в директории /home/ubuntu/project/ .
Вот ссылка на файлы приложения https://github.com/cs-hse-projects/Instagram_Analyze_Gadetsky_103

Как решить проблему? Давал папке project права с помощью chmod, при запуске выдает 500 internal error.

Comment: @thmw, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, есть ли доступ к файлам Instagram_Analyze_Gadetsky_103 у приложения на 5000 порту. И способно ли вообще приложение на 5000 порту выполнять Instagram_Analyze_Gadetsky_103.